# Creating dynamic radio inputs for multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

**I have a wireframe that I am building.**

[image]

**What I am Doing & What I am Trying to Achieve:**

- We have not integrated a back end yet but I am using AngularJS. However, I am not actually using AngularJS directives yet. So far I am using plain Vanilla JavaScript to build all of the 8 wireframes and their content.
- About 6/8 of the slides are almost identical. They have the same exact radio buttons (low, med, high) but they each have different header text (the label in blue). At this point I have finished building the 2nd slide (which is the 1st slide that uses the radio input layout). Everything seems fine and dandy but now that I am moving on to build the 3rd slide, which is using the radio buttons as well, my code is starting to look very redundant and I can already tell this will end up being extremely verbose when I finish the JavaScript code for all 6 of the slides that have the same 3 radio buttons.

**This is My Code prior to me attempting to integrate a function that can help automate the radio creation process for the slides: **

```js
var initialize = function() { 
  
  //        =================
  //   FOR THE 2ND SLIDE
  //      =================
  var s2 = document.getElementById("slide2");
  var s2Label = document.createElement("label");
     s2Label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Works with minors, elderly, ill or other potentially vulnerable person?"));
  s2.appendChild(s2Label);

  var slide2CboxContainer.document.createElement("Div");
  slide2CboxContainer.setAttribute("id", "slide2-cbox-container");
  slide2CboxContainer.setAttribute("class", "row");
  s2.appendChild(slide2CboxContainer);

  var counter2 = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    slide2CboxContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("Div")).setAttribute("id", "slide2checkbox" + counter2++);
  };

  // for radio inputs on slide 2  --  (s2c1, s2c2, s2c3)
  var s2c1 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox1");
  var s2c2 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox2");
  var s2c3 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox3");
  
  
  // creating text labels for each radio input -- reusable
  var low = document.createElement("p");
      low.setAttribute("class", "low");
  low.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Low"));

  var med = document.createElement("p");
      med.setAttribute("class", "med");
   med.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Med"));

  var high = document.createElement("p");
      high.setAttribute("class", "high");    high.appendChild(document.createTextNode("High"));

  
   var l = document.createElement("label");
       l.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
   var i = document.createElement("input");
       i.setAttribute("type", "radio");
       i.setAttribute("name", "optradio");
       i.setAttribute("class", "radio");
       l.appendChild(i);
      s2c1.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
       s2c1.appendChild(l);
       s2c1.appendChild(low);


   var l = document.createElement("label");
       l.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
   var i = document.createElement("input");
       i.setAttribute("type", "radio");
       i.setAttribute("name", "optradio");
       i.setAttribute("class", "radio");
       l.appendChild(i);
       s2c2.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
       s2c2.appendChild(l);
       s2c2.appendChild(med);


    var l = document.createElement("label");
        l.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
    var i = document.createElement("input");
        i.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        i.setAttribute("name", "optradio");
        i.setAttribute("class", "radio");
        l.appendChild(i);
        s2c3.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
        s2c3.appendChild(l);
        s2c3.appendChild(high);


  //    =================
  //    FOR THE 3RD SLIDE
  //    =================
  
    var s3 = document.getElementById("slide3");
    var s3Label = document.createElement("label");
        s3Label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Fiduciary responsibility/Access to Cash?"));
     s3.appendChild(s3Label);

  var slide3CboxContainer = document.createElement("Div");
   slide3CboxContainer.setAttribute("id", "slide3-cbox-container");
     slide3CboxContainer.setAttribute("class", "row");
   s3.appendChild(slide3CboxContainer);
    var counter3 = 1;
   for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {  slide3CboxContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("Div")).setAttribute("id", "slide3checkbox" + counter3++);
    };
  
  //this is where I would keep rewriting the same code to create the checkboxes
  var s3c1 = document.getElementById("slide3checkbox1");
  var s3c2 = document.getElementById("slide3checkbox2");
  var s3c3 = document.getElementById("slide3checkbox3");
  
};
initialize();
```

```css
#tab-container {
  height: 15em;
  width: 5%;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  margin-top: 6em;
}
.tab {
  height: .5em;
  width: 12%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 1.2em auto;
  background-color: #10b9e4;
}
#slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12%;
  height: 18em;
  width: 76%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  z-index: -2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#slide2-cbox-container,
#slide3-cbox-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#slide2checkbox1,
#slide2checkbox2,
#slide2checkbox3,
#slide3checkbox1,
#slide3checkbox2,
#slide3checkbox3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 7em;
}
.low,
.med,
.high {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.radio {
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
#slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 14%;
  height: 18em;
  width: 72%;
  margin-top: -2em;
  z-index: -3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
label {
      display: block;
      /*margin: 30px 0 0 0;*/
      margin-top: 4em;
      text-align: center;
      /*float:left;*/
    }
```

```html
<div id="container" ng-app="cscoringApp" ng-controller="jobsController">

  <!-- for the blue tabs/dots -->
  <div id="tab-container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab7" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab8" class="tab"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="slideContainer" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-     offset-2" style="margin-top:5em;">

  </div>
```

**This is my JavaScript code where I am currently trying to integrate a function to automate the button creation**

- This function works but it only works for the last radio button with the label "high" (s2c3).

```js
var s2c1 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox1");
var s2c2 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox2");
var s2c3 = document.getElementById("slide2checkbox3");
     

var create = function(a, b, c){
 var l = document.createElement("label");
     l.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
    var i = document.createElement("input");
        i.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        i.setAttribute("name", "optradio");
        i.setAttribute("class", "radio");
     l.appendChild(i);  
        a.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
        a.appendChild(l);
        a.appendChild(low);
        b.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
        b.appendChild(l);
        b.appendChild(med);
        c.setAttribute("class", "checkbox-inline");
        c.appendChild(l);
        c.appendChild(high);
       
      };
      create(s2c1, s2c2, s2c3);
```